# Load image and remove when authentification is required

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, authentication, load

I am grabbing some (random) images from a search machine and display them to the users. The problem is: It may happen that some images require a http authentification (username/password). I dont want to have those images... they should be removed without displaying the popup where you can enter the username and password.

Actually I am using simple jquery methods to display my images.

```
var displayNode = ....
....
var m_img = $("<img />", {src : "...."});
m_img.bind('error', function (e) {
  $(this).remove();
});
displayNode.append(m_img);
```

Now I load the image directly and if an error occurs it will be removed. But.. when server sends back a HTTP (Basic) Authentification flag this is of course not an error. Hence there is an input prompt. When I click on "cancel" the propmt closes, jquery treats this as an error and removes the image.

So.. what is the best way to check if there is authentification and if not display it to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a HEAD request that only returns headers, then check the headers for the authentication header before actually making the request:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

You would use this method to first check the headers, then if OK, get the image. You'll have to test it with your protected resource, I'm not sure what the browser will do when requesting just the HEAD and I don't have a local protected resource to test against (CORS got me on the online resources I was trying to test against). Fiddle:

```
var basicAuthProtectedURL = 'http://fiddle.jshell.net';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("HEAD", basicAuthProtectedURL, true);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()); //all headers
      console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')); //just the one you want
      if (xhr.getResponseHeader('WWW-Authenticate')) {
          console.log('I got the authentication header, skip this request.');
      } else {
          console.log('no header, resource unsecure');
      }
    } else {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  console.error(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.send(null);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5z5bnwgz/

Post back how it goes!

Comment: I tried using HEAD as well but there are some issues.  First there is the problem of cross origin domains (jquery has the crossDomain flag). 

Second: The onload event is not triggered at all if the server returns a 401 response. The solution might look like this: If onerror is triggered -> remove the image. If onload is triggered and readystate is 4 -> the image is available and can be loaded.

Comment: that seems totally reasonable to me... as long as it doesnt trigger the username/pwd prompt.